# How to Set Dynamically UIScrollView height based on UITableView height?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uiscrollview

I'm able to give height of scrollview based on tableview content height but sometimes scrollview height is not scrolled and sometime scrollview height is giving me perfect height based on tableview , I'm confused its not giving me each and every time when I run app its not giving  perfect height based on tableview. And in my both tableview data are from Web and is it I'm not getting scrollview height based on tableview height because of Internet Slow so it is loading data slow in tableview ??

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if tableView == tableview{
        let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! noticeTableViewCell
        let noticedata = notices[indexPath.row]

        cell.noticeText.text =  noticedata.notice

             tableviewheightConstraint.constant = tableView.contentSize.height
//            scrollview.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: tableview.frame.origin.y + tableView.contentSize.height )

            return cell

        } else  {
            let cell = pendingtableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "pendingbillcell", for: indexPath) as! PendingbillTableViewCell

            let getdata = pendingbillsdata[indexPath.row]

            let date = getdata.date
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
            let dateFromString : NSDate = dateFormatter.date(from: date)! as NSDate
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
            let datenew = dateFormatter.string(from: dateFromString as Date)

            cell.billnotext.text = getdata.Billno
            cell.datetext.text = datenew
            cell.amounttext.text = getdata.amount
            cell.statustext.text = getdata.status

            pendingtableviewheightConstraint.constant = tableView.contentSize.height
            scrollview.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: pendingtableview.frame.origin.y + tableView.contentSize.height)
            return cell
        }

    }
```

Or do I missing something in code that I am not getting , can this issue be solved ?

Comment: why you are wanna change scrollview height instead of it's contentsize?

Answer (score 3):

The following way works goods.just check it out

Make IBOutlets for scrollView,ContentView,tableView & height Constraint for tableView(to adjust height based on content)

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView:UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var contentView:UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView:UITableView!

@IBOutlet var heightConstraints:NSLayoutConstraints!
```

In viewDidLoad method

```
    // set delagte & datasource to tableView
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delagte = self

    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 40

    // force the layout of subviews before drawing
    self.defineTableView.layoutIfNeeded()

    // Observer for oreientation change
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.updateScrollViewContentSize), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
```

in viewDidAppear method

```
// calling to update scrollView contentSize after all views initialize done.
self.updateScrollViewContentSize()
```

Method to calculating content size of UIScrollView

```
@objc private func updateScrollViewContentSize(){
    // set dynamic height constant of tableView
    self.heightConstraints.constant = self.tableView.contentSize.height + 10.0
    var heightOfSubViews:CGFloat = 0.0
    for views in self.contentView.subviews {
        if views is UITableView {
            heightOfSubViews = heightOfSubViews + (views as! UITableView).contentSize.height + 10.0
        }else {
            heightOfSubViews = heightOfSubViews + views.frame.size.height
        }
    }

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize.init(width: self.scrollView.frame.size.width, height: heightOfSubViews + 50.0) // 50.0 - space b/w controls(30.0) + extras spaces (20.0)
}
```

Comment: @IBOutlet var heightConstraints:NSLayoutConstraints! is this for viewHeight ??

Comment: @BikeshThakur  heightConstraints for tableViewheight

Comment: it not updating scrollview height or view height

Comment: @BikeshThakur i m not posting for scrollView height that constraints for tableView height based on content.

Comment: why you are wanna change scrollview height instead of it's contentsize?

Comment: i was trying to change scrollview height cause **contentview UIVIEW** height was not updating so n its no even changing height of content view

Comment: and i am increasing height of scrollview because when tableview height is incease more than height of 1200 than i need to increase  it and mine tableview row contents are increasing according to its data

Comment: don't increase height of scrollview instead update contentsize like above code.seems you are not understanding purpose of scrollview.check with other scrollview tutorials

Comment: i have added ur code n it does not even update contentsize of contentview

Comment: i  put this function **updateScrollViewContentSize()** in tableview cellforRow and it update the contentsize of view and sometimes it is not being updated is it because of internet slow so it cannot count the height of tableview contentsize being loaded from web